# Use assign() function to assign column names into an empty data frame in R

Tags: r, assignment-operator

I have an empty data frame, whose name was created by assign() function.

```
x <- "Sale"
y <- "2015"
col_names <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3")
assign(paste0(x,y), data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(col_names))))
```

content of x,y and col_names was dynamic.
How should I assign col_names to the data frame: "paste0(x,y)" ?

```
assign(colnames(paste0(x,y)),col_names)
```

I've tried this , but in vain.
Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: why do you need `assign`?  `colnames(Sale2015) <- col_names`

Comment: Because x and y was dynamic.

Comment: Because x and y was dynamic. If I wrote colnames(Sale2015) <- col_names, I would edit the code every year, even every month (eg.Sale201502)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty you're having (how do I refer in later code to an object created with a dynamically generated name) is precisely why `assign` is a bad idea. Your problem is actually *caused* by your desire to use `assign`.

Put the data frame in a list with a non-dynamic variable name, and set the name of that element of the list using the "dynamic" elements:

```
a <- list(setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(col_names))),col_names))
names(a) <- paste0(x,y)

> a
$Sale2015
[1] Q1 Q2 Q3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can include a call to `setNames` in your `assign` statement:

```
assign(paste0(x,y), 
       setNames(data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(col_names))), 
                col_names)
```

**example:**

```
assign("dfa", setNames(data.frame(1:3), "col1"))
> dfa
#  col1
#1    1
#2    2
#3    3
```

Comment: I prefer these 1-step (1-liner) processes over multiple liners ALWAYS !!

Answer (score 2):

If you have already created the dataset, the generic replacement function `names<-` can be used to change the existing column names of the dataset with the one in 'col_names' vector.

```
assign(paste0(x,y), `names<-`(get(paste0(x,y)), col_names))
```